# Mailto Link within SSRS report

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, mailto

So as the title really, I can't seem to get it to work, it works if I only include one email in the TO: field however I need two. I have a table with all the reports we own and it has two fields, owner and deputy owner and I want to create a hyperlink which emails both of these recipients if there are any queries which the user can click and then it already populates the owners of the report and their email addresses in the To: field, however there are more than one owner which is the issue I am facing.

I tried joining the two fields together and adding a semicolon between them, I tried adding a comma also. This didn't work and I've tried to add them in separately.

Please Help!

My Fields!Owner.Value is set to for example jb@123.com;pj@123.com

Any ideas?

This is my expression:

```
="mailto:" & First(Fields!owner.Value, "DataSet2") & "?subject=" & First(Fields!report.Value, "DataSet2") & "&cc=" & First(Fields!dev_ib.Value, "DataSet2")
```

I have also tried

```
="mailto:" & First(Fields!owner.Value, "DataSet2") & ";" & First(Fields!owner2.Value, "DataSet2") & "?subject=" & First(Fields!report.Value, "DataSet2") & "&cc=" & First(Fields!dev_ib.Value, "DataSet2")
```

EDIT: I've seen people say it is not possible to have more than one To: recipient in SSRS, can anyone confirm if this is still true, if so I will give up I guess....

Comment: have you tried just copy/pasting the URL into a browser to see if it's valid? mailto: should support more than one address although MS Docs differ from the standards . MS says use a semi-colon to separate whereas official docs on mailto protocol state use a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript

I hadn't been able to get the mailto to work with multiple addresses with a comma or semi-colon - it gives an rsInvalidURLProtocol error.

But if I use javascript, it does work.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('mailto:" & First(Fields!owner.Value, "DataSet2") & ";" & First(Fields!owner2.Value, "DataSet2") & "'))"
```

[image]

We have Outlook so I used semi-colons.

This might be blocked by group policy - I get a warning about it.

[image]